# Autolayout vs. different XIB for different form factors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, autolayout

I am working on a universal application that must support all current iOS device form factors. The interface is using autolayout via storyboards and currently displays correctly on the iPad, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus form factors. However, I am struggling with getting the interface / constraints to properly scale on the iPhone 5 / SE form factor. Does anyone have recommendations for how I can fix my constraints on the iPhone 5 / SE form factor or would you just recommend loading a different XIB for the iPhone 5 / SE? Thanks in advance.

Correct interface on an iPhone 6S:
[image: Correct interface on an iPhone 6S]

Broken interface on iPhone 5 / SE:
[image: Broken interface on iPhone 5 / SE]

(This is the only view giving me a hard time).

Comment: Are you using size classes?

Comment: The problem is that the smallest size class lumps in 3.5in, 4in, and 4.7in form factors. Which doesn't allow me to distinguish between the iPhone 5 / SE and the 6 form factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rule of thumb is to design storyboards for the `Any x Any` size class, and then make specific changes for other sizes as needed. This is because `Any x Any` forces you to think in terms of resizable components and relative positioning because you're working with a 600 x 600 size that doesn't actually exist on any device. My guess is that your design has fixed vertical constraints between components, when what you want is for some of them to be relative. In other words, it looks like your Login button, `-- or --` separator, and TouchID views are at fixed distances from the bottom edge of the view, and the others are fixed from the top edge. If autolayout can't compute the desired distances at runtime, it will pick one constraint to turn off in order to resolve problems; in this case, it's your vertical constraint between the bottom of the password field to the top of the Login button. Instead, I'd make the constraint between the TouchID button and the bottom of the view a less-than-or-equal constraint, not an equals, and/or give it a lower priority than the other vertical constraints.

Comment: Thank you! Laying out the elements in the inferred layout made a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using different objects which are not over lapping. 
So you can use `stack View` for your application.
Group your objects and than apply constraints to it
It will reduce complexity and also give better performance to your application
Also solve your problem.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, in general, but in practice, UIs that you lay out using a lot of `UIStackView`s really look like crap. You have to really fiddle with the `UIStackViewDistribution` values to get what you want.

Comment: By seeing the problem stackview solve the problem because not much objects are there so